# What exact breed of animal is a 金丝熊?

Tags: meaning

金丝熊 is easily available from local animal markets in my wife's home town. We asked the owners of different stores and they say it is not a mouse.

So what exactly is it, is it just a fancy name for a mouse or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, it is "Mesocricetus auratus" ([Golden hamster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_hamster)) ([source1](http://baike.baidu.com/view/807094.htm) [source2](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/zh/wiki/%E9%87%91%E4%B8%9D%E7%86%8A)). It belong to "仓鼠科", and it should a kind of "鼠类" in Chinese.

However, as not everybody is a biologist, and as the name for it is "金丝**熊**", it may not be treated as mouse in everyday life.

Another reason is that "鼠" does not carry a good meaning in Chinese. It is often related to "stealing" or something alike. So it may be avoided to name a kind pet animal. (However, we do have "仓鼠" for pets.)

btw: To be honest, I've never seen a real "金丝熊".

Comment: These were spotted in 苏州的一个花鸟市场 so maybe a southern thing

Answer (score 0):

According to [Baidu Baike](http://baike.baidu.com/view/807094.htm), it's a **Syrian Hamster** or a **Golden Hamster**. I'd say it's safe to say it's a hamster.

Hope that helps!